# How to get conversationTopic in Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

Earlier we were using Exchange Service to read outlook mails. And we were able to get conversation topic. But now in Graph API we are only getting conversationId and conversationIndex.
Is ther any way to get conversavtionTopic in graph api.

Example:
subject: [EXTERNAL] Test-1
conversationTopic: Test-1

subject: [EXTERNAL] RE: Test-1
conversationTopic: Test-1

ConversationTopic
Contains a normalized form of the subject value that was set on the original message. This is the same as the Thread-Topic message header. This value is read-only.

I tried to use conversationId to search if I can find conversation topic but could't find anything.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter= conversationId eq 'yourConversationId'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Graph doesn't provide that as a strongly typed property but you can query the PR_CONVERSATION_TOPIC property using the ExtendedProperty definition eg

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'string 0x0070')
```